# Saving values within if statement C#

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie at C# and I'm having some difficulties writing a program that is going to let you save values in a variable, everything is working fine, except I can't save values into my variable. Here's the code:

```
while (true)
{
    //Menu
    Console.WriteLine (" \n\tWelcome!");
    Console.WriteLine (" \t[1]Store value");
    Console.WriteLine (" \t[2]Write message");
    Console.WriteLine (" \t[3]Clear the console");
    Console.WriteLine (" \t[4]Shut down program");
    Console.Write("\tChoose: ");

    //Users choice
    int choice = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
    //Users message
    string usrMsg = null;

    //if statement 
    if (choice == 1) {
        usrMsg += Console.ReadLine ();
    } else if (choice == 2) {
        Console.WriteLine (usrMsg);
    } else if (choice == 3) {
        //Shuts down program
        break;
    } else if (choice == 4) {
        //Clear program
        Console.Clear ();
    } 
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("please enter a number between 1-4");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? What did you expect it to do and what does it do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Be aware since you create new `usrMsg` in every iteration, it won't _save_ the old value. Other than that, please clearly explain what do you mean by _I can't save values into my variable_ exactly. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: `"a program that is going to let you save values in a variable, everything is working fine, except I can't save values into my variable"` - So everything isn't working fine then? ;)

Comment: @Alex Consider use `switch case` instead all the `if..else..if..` and put the `Convert.ToInt32` withing a `try-catch` block

Comment: You mismatch your menue items 3 and 4 - when user enters 3 (clear console) you make the break!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this runs it always creates userMsg as null. That means that at best it will 'save' only 1 value when the user chooses '1'. However, this will never get displayed if the user selects '2' as when the user gets to the menu again userMsg will have been set to null again.

My assumption is that you're trying to save the number of times someone has selected '1' and then display that if the user then hits option '2'.

Stick this:

```
//Users message
string usrMsg = null;
```

outside of the 'while' loop.

Comment: It's working now, thank you! Is there someway to clear the variable aswell?

Comment: Just make an new option fx. `if(choice == 5) string userMsg = null;`

Comment: @Alex - that would depend on how you want to clear it. If you want the user to be able to clear it like they were able to store it then add another menu item and under that choice just put userMsg = null; Also, if this worked please mark this as the answer.

Comment: It's now working the way I want it to! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Alex - why have you now removed my answer from being the correct one? My answer is correct and was answered much sooner than hamzeh.

Comment: Whops, sorry! I'm new to this and realized only now that I can't have two correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

You just move the usrMsg variable out of while block as a global the value will be saved.

```
        //Users message
        string usrMsg = null;

        while (true)
        {
            //Menu
            Console.WriteLine(" \n\tWelcome!");
            Console.WriteLine(" \t[1]Store value");
            Console.WriteLine(" \t[2]Write message");
            Console.WriteLine(" \t[3]Clear the console");
            Console.WriteLine(" \t[4SShut down program");
            Console.Write("\tChoose: ");

            //Users choice
            int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            //if statement 
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                usrMsg += Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (choice == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(usrMsg);
            }
            else if (choice == 3)
            {
                //Shuts down program
                break;
            }
            else if (choice == 4)
            {
                //Clear program
                Console.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("please enter a number between 1-4");
            }
        }
```